# ExecuteScalar returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, transactions

I have an sql query that uses transactions, and it uses return to indicate failure or success, like so:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE @intErrorCode INT;
    DECLARE @emailAutoIncrement INT;

    BEGIN TRAN


    INSERT  INTO Accounts ( blabla, blabla2 )
    VALUES  ( somevalue, somevalue2 )

    Select @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    if (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN 1


    PROBLEM:
    if (@intErrorCode <> 0) Begin
    Rollback Tran
    RETURN 0
    END

END
```

From code, I used `sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` thinking that this will give me either 1 or 0, but this always returns false. Also, another problem I have is that when an exception happens in the sql and the program is meant to return 0, it actually returns the exception.

So the `RETURN 0` is useless because it is always overridden by the exception?

To add some more information, the sql query is a stored procedure and it is called like so:

```
                myCommand.CommandText = "createAccount";
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //Add parameters here
                using (myReader)
                {
                    var test = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your variable declaration inside your transaction scope?

Comment: Why? That doesn't seem related. The transaction works and returns the value when ran from SQL Management Studio, the problem is from my C# code.

Comment: Try SET @intErrorCode = @@ERROR rather than SELECT - see my answer for a full solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `SELECT` rather than `RETURN`

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE @intErrorCode INT;
    DECLARE @emailAutoIncrement INT;

    BEGIN TRAN


    INSERT  INTO Accounts ( blabla, blabla2 )
    VALUES  ( somevalue, somevalue2 )

    SET @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    if (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

    COMMIT TRAN
    SELECT 1


    PROBLEM:
    if (@intErrorCode <> 0) Begin
    Rollback Tran
    SELECT 0
    END

END
```

I also changed

```
SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
```

to

```
SET @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks, solved dual errors. I found out I can use `@RETURN_VALUE` and do it the proper way, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of Return 1 to use Select 1

For the second problem in MSSQL is recommended to use try catch blocks.

This is what I use, don't know if it is best practice, but it allows more possibilities, you can log errors, customize the text of messages

```
BEGIN TRY...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(4000),@ErrorSeverity int,@ErrorState int
    select @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),@ErrorState=ERROR_STATE()
    set @ErrorState=case when isnull(@ErrorState,0) <1 then 1 else @ErrorState end  
    raiserror (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Comment: Hmmm... come to think of it, the return isnt really needed. I can just watch for exceptions.  The only time the query will execute correctly is when there are no exceptions. Or is this bad programming practice? I can atleast remove the return on the rollback.